# Error with console output in Python 3.7.4 on Windows (pytest 5.0.1)

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytest

I recently installed python 3.7.4 and pytest 5.0.1 on windows 7.
On the first try to run (on windows command prompt) a simple pytest command as:

`pytest --version` I got a long traceback with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)   
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 55, in main
        config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 200, in _prepareconfig
        pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
        return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
        return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
        firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
        gen.send(outcome)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 89, in pytest_cmdline_parse
        config = outcome.get_result()   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
        raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
        res = hook_impl.function(*args)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 661, in pytest_cmdline_parse
        self.parse(args)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 869, in parse
        self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 825, in _preparse
        early_config=self, args=args, parser=self._parser   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
        return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
        return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
        firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,   File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
        return outcome.get_result()   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
        raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 182, in _multicall
        next(gen)  # first yield   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 42, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
        _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround(sys.stdout)   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 815, in _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround
        sys.stdin = _reopen_stdio(sys.stdin, "rb")   
File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 808, in _reopen_stdio
        open(os.dup(f.fileno()), mode, buffering), OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is your `pytest --version` supposed to do? Aren't you supposed to run `pytest yourtest.py` instead? If you want to check your pytest version, you should do `pip list`

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback to your question? @ycx `pytest --version` is the correct way of checking `pytest` version and listing installed plugins.

Comment: What is the folder where the `cmd` is? Is there anything specific about permissions that you have in this folder?

Comment: @sophros c:\Users\xxx>

Comment: @hoefling I have updated the post with the full traceback. 10X

Comment: Looks like a `pytest` bug - I would open a [new issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/new).

Comment: @hoefling I downgraded to 3.7.3 and it indeed working. Thanks guys.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://bugs.python.org/issue37267 change in 3.7.4 and reported regression for Win7 https://bugs.python.org/issue37549